# Jquery UI Tabs randomly creating empty divs

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

First off I should say that my problem is very specific and I'm not expecting a direct resolution, I'm more hoping for possibilities.

I've got jquery tabs set to load on document ready. 8/10 times it works perfectly, but occasionally instead of setting up the existing divs correctly, it goes and inserts its own empty tab container divs into the DOM, and all the hidden content is shown instead. I've figured out that using the refresh method will fix the issue, but it does not remove the phantom DOM elements.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline" href="#tabs-1">Overview</a></li>
<li><a style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline" href="#tabs-2">How to apply</a></li>
<li><a style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline" href="#tabs-3">Obligations</a></li>
<li><a style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline" href="#tabs-4">Forms and fees</a></li>
<li><a style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline" href="#tabs-5">FAQs</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="ui-id-30" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-29" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false"></div>
<div id="ui-id-32" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-31" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="ui-id-34" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-33" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="ui-id-36" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-35" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="ui-id-38" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-37" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
<div id="tabs-4"></div>
<div id="tabs-5"></div>
</div>
```

As seen above, Jquery UI is inserting the 5 divs with the ID's 'ui-id-30' and so on.

At first I thought the issue was because my content was being loaded into the page slightly after the document was ready via Ajax but i've been unable to confirm if that is the case or not. (I work in Oracle Service Cloud).

If you guys have any ideas I'd love to hear them! Many thanks.

Comment: I've subsequently found out that the issue of it being sporadic was to do with another Oracle function that was going in to the page and transforming the tab links with releative url paths. The reason it was failing some of the time is because occasionally the tab initialise would run before the transform function and it would post a 403 console error.

Comment: looks like you know what's wrong with your code..? Just make sure you initialize jquery widget after all your other stuff is done..? What are we supposed to do here..?